# "|" character will get ignored

Tags: regex

I have the string `[TITLE|suffix=my value|prefix=another value]` and I would like to get the match of `my value`.

This is what I have tried:

```
(?<=TITLE\|suffix=).+[^|\]]
```

But then the match will be `my value|prefix=another value]`.

Why is it ignoring the character `|` after `my value`?

See here: https://regexr.com/5h0h2

Comment: Like `(?<=TITLE\|suffix=)[^|]+` https://regex101.com/r/Y5no64/1/

Comment: It matches exeactly what you told it - everything (`.+`)  after `TITLE|suffix=`. You either want lazy matching `.+?` or to just math anything that's *not* a `|`  or `]` character: `[[^|\]]+`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think OP wants *not* either of `|` or `]` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/Y5no64/2).

Comment: @VLAZ You are right, I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, maybe `TITLE\|suffix=\K[^|\]]+` works =)

Comment: "*just math anything*" ...oops. Kids, don't drink and math. I meant mat**c**h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should exclude the `|` and `]` from being part of the match using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and repeat the character class.

```
(?<=TITLE\|suffix=)[^|\]]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z2lsZL/1)